# How to plot multiple GAMM smooths in one ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, gratia

I'm hoping to plot my global effect `s(CYR.std)`, along with my site deviations `s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs")` term in ggplot. I can plot one at a time, but can't figure out how to include both in the same plot. I'm not sure if I'm specifying things correctly along the way, or how to add the `s(CYR.std)` term on top of the factor-smooth term, for comparison.

```
set.seed(12345)

library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

# Hypothetical fish counts from negative binomial distribution
df <- as.data.frame(rnbinom(1000, mu = 0.6971, size = 1))

df$year <- rep(2011:2020, each=100)
df$CYR.std <- df$year - min(df$year)
df$fCYR <- as.factor(df$year)

df$site <- seq(1, 50, 1)
df$fSite <- as.factor(df$site)

df$season <- rep(c("DRY", "WET"), each=50)
df$fSeason <- as.factor(df$season)

# Salinity (continuous covariate)
df$sal <- sample(0.5:40, 1000, replace = TRUE)

names(df)[1] <- "count"

m <- bam(count ~ s(sal) + 
           s(CYR.std) + 
           fSeason + 
           s(CYR.std, by = fSeason) + 
           s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs") + 
           s(fCYR, bs = "re"), 
         method = "fREML",
         discrete = TRUE,
         select = TRUE, 
         family = nb(link = "log"),
         data = df)


# Site deviations from global term
ds <- data_slice(m, CYR.std = evenly(CYR.std),
                 fSite = evenly(fSite))

fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response") # density

ggplot(fv, aes(x = CYR.std, y = fitted, color = fSite)) +
  # geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()


# Global term
ds2 <- data_slice(m, CYR.std = evenly(CYR.std))

fv2 <- fitted_values(m, data = ds2, scale = "response") # density

ggplot(fv2, aes(x = CYR.std, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

**Is this the correct way to specify plotting the 'fs' term and how do I combine both plots?**

Comment: `geom_ribbon` takes a `data` argument as well. Pass multiple of those.

Comment: 'geom_ribbon' only produces the confidence intervals though. I excluded those so I could at least differentiate all lines by fSite, because there are so many of them. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, it is hard to visualize what th e output looks like without example data. All `geom_*` commands take a `data` argument.

Comment: I included example data. Which df should I use fv or fv2?

Comment: What packages provide `bam`, `data_slice`, and `fitted_values`? It's more normal to provide a dput

Comment: Ah, good point. I updated my question. dput created too much code in the past b/c my dataset is too large, so I opted for this method to save space.

Comment: Note that while Allan's answer is how I would do it, your `fv` is incorrect. If your aim is to plot the global effect you need to exclude the the `fs` smooth from the predictions. If you look at `fv` you are conditioning on one of the levels in `fSite`. This is unavoidable and documented as `predict` needs all variables. To exlude the `fs` smooth from the predictions, add `exclude = "s(CYR.std,fSite)"` to the `fitted_values() call. You'll likely want to exclude `"s(sal)"` and also the ´by` smooths. Use `gratia::smooths(m)` to get the names of the smooths to add to the `exclude` vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Allan's answer is correct from the plotting point of view, the OP has incorrectly specified how the predicted values are generated if the aim is to plot the global effect on top of the site specific effects.

Here's a corrected version

```r
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Your model has the following smooths:

```r
gratia::smooths(m)
```

```
> gratia::smooths(m)
[1] "s(sal)"                "s(CYR.std)"            "s(CYR.std):fSeasonDRY"
[4] "s(CYR.std):fSeasonWET" "s(CYR.std,fSite)"      "s(fCYR)"
```

and there is the parametric `fSeason` effects.

When you generate predictions from a GAM you need to provide values for all variables used in the model. But as this model is additive we can leave out the effects of one or more terms. We do this by selecting terms or excluding terms in the call to `predict.gam()` or `gratia::fitted_values()`.

If we look at your first `data_slice()`

```r
# Site deviations from global term
ds <- data_slice(m, CYR.std = evenly(CYR.std),
                 fSite = evenly(fSite))
```

we see that values have been created for all the unstated variables in the the model, including `sal` and `fSeason`

```
> ds
# A tibble: 5,000 × 5
   CYR.std fSite fSeason   sal fCYR 
     <dbl> <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <fct>
 1       0 1     DRY      19.5 2011 
 2       0 2     DRY      19.5 2011 
 3       0 3     DRY      19.5 2011 
 4       0 4     DRY      19.5 2011 
 5       0 5     DRY      19.5 2011 
 6       0 6     DRY      19.5 2011 
 7       0 7     DRY      19.5 2011 
 8       0 8     DRY      19.5 2011 
 9       0 9     DRY      19.5 2011 
10       0 10    DRY      19.5 2011 
# ℹ 4,990 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

and the predictions are conditional upon *all* these values.

We can remove the effects of everything but `s(CYR.std)` and `s(CYR.std,fSite)`, but getting these predictions to be agnostic of the season is trickier because of the treatment contrasts; the intercept term will be for the reference season, `DRY`. Either you'll need to accept this and indicate that these are conditional upon the season, or produce predictions for both seasons. And if you do that, then should you include the  factor by smooth effects of `CYR.std)`?

Let's assume you don't care that the predictions are for the `DRY` season. Then to exclude everything but the two required effects we would do:

```r
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response",
  terms = c("(Intercept)", "s(CYR.std)", "s(CYR.std,fSite)"))
```

That will give only the effects of the two requested smooths and the model constant term.

Likewise, for the global term only, we need to exclude certain effects:

```r
# Global term
ds2 <- data_slice(m, CYR.std = evenly(CYR.std))
fv2 <- fitted_values(m, data = ds2, scale = "response",
  terms = c("(Intercept)", "s(CYR.std)"))
```

I'm using `terms` instead of `exclude` here as it is easier to select which terms to include rather than to list the ones we want to exclude in this instance.

Now you can follow Allan's example, thought I have modified it to use the development version of {gratia} as I have modified the names of variables returned:

```r
ggplot(fv2, aes(x = CYR.std, y = .fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .lower_ci, ymax = .upper_ci), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(data = fv, aes(x = CYR.std, y = .fitted, color = fSite)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, linetype = 2)
```

This gives

[image]

Note now how the credible interval that is on the global smooth is actually for this smooth (plus intercept)

Comment: Thanks Gavin ! So, if I wanted to do the same thing for the other season (wet season), could I not simply change the reference level? As an aside, my main term s(CYR.std) had an edf near zero.

Comment: If you change the reference level you change the model and need to refit. You can *predict* for the other level by specifying it in the data slice `fSeason = evenly(fSeason)` as well as the other terms you mention. But then your `fv` etc will contain two sets of predictions, one per season, so you might want to add `+ facet_wrap(~ fSeason)` to the ggplot call. Beyond that, I think you would need to look at using different contrasts for `fSeason` to see about getting one where the reference level is the average of all the levels - which I believe can be done

Answer (score 2):

You can plot both together by passing the data you want to the specific layers that represent that data:

```r
ggplot(fv2, aes(x = CYR.std, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(data = fv, aes(x = CYR.std, y = fitted, color = fSite)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Allan! I assumed I specified the code correctly, sorry for the confusion!